# Sync multiple devices with Core Data

Tags: core-data, swift3, icloud, ios10, cloudkit

I have a coredata app that I would love to be able to share the same data with multiple devices, possibly with iCloud/cloud kit. I am not sure where to start, or how to go about it? The only thing I can think of, but still not sure how to do, would be to sync the SQLite files with iCloud? Not sure if thats a good idea or not? I just recently converted my app over to swift 3 and iOS10 core data code. The only way I am able to share data between devices currently is thru iTunes files sharing.

For whatever reason this topic is hard to find modern info on.

Comment: did you find anyother good solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Data doesn't have support for this. Except for the built-in iCloud sync, but that's deprecated as of iOS 10.

You could use CloudKit to sync data, but you'll have to write your own code to convert between Core Data's persistent store and CloudKit's online store. It's not impossible but it's certainly not automatic.

Syncing the SQLite file is not a good idea unless you really want to corrupt the data.

Comment: Damn. That's what I was afraid of. Fingers crossed my problem gets solved WWDC'17 

Comment: File an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com and it just might help.